# RavenDB Studio doesnt display query results

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I created an index and I tried to query the index. However, the studio doesn't display the result. It displays a "Loading please wait..." and "No results were found. For NotAnalyzed fields you may wish to search with [[term]]." messages.

[image]

I'm using Server Build #30141. Am I missing any configuration settings?

Comment: Can you try to zoom out (Ctrl + -) in the browser?

Comment: And, failing that, let's see your index definition.

Comment: @AyendeRahien Thank you. Zooming out helped.